# XCode12 Allegro "file not found"

Tags: macos, c++11, linker-errors, xcode12, allegro5

I could use some help solving a linker error. Could just be because I'm new to developing for MacOS. I got my Allegro Libraries off of Homebrew by using `brew install allegro`. I followed the steps on the tutorial I watched nearly to a tee, as I opened XCode to make a Cocoa app, went to the target, edited my build settings, and changed my Header search path to `/usr/local/include/**` and my Library search path to `/usr/local/lib/**`, as well as set my Framework search path to `/Library/Frameworks/**`. I set my C++ dialect to GNU++11. I went back into my terminal, where I used the commands to pull up my Allegro libraries in the Cellar. I picked out all the necessary files to make the game work, and then drag n' dropped them all into my linked frameworks and libraries. I created a Copy Files build phase with a destination of my frameworks, and drag n' dropped those same Allegro files into it as folder references as shown here:
[My files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmYj5.png) After all that, it was time to create my main.cpp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_acodec.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_audio.h>
// ...
```

...and there in laid the problem. I had gotten the error: `'allegro5\allegro.h' file not found`. Upon double checking by commenting out the troublesome lines, it had turned out none of the files I #included could be found. Is there some kind of step I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was weird. I ran the code and suddenly all the errors went away. XCode can be so weird sometimes.